# Trouble with JFrame sizing and title bar color

Tags: java, jframe, behavior

I'm having relatively simple trouble with my GUI, I want to open a JFrame as the window for my app, I want it maximised and not resizable which I have done but two problems exist, firstly, it seems to work but if I click and drag on the title bar it detaches from maximised, I have read all the advice and implemented it but I find this annoying as I would like it to just stay maximised.
Secondly, the title bar is grey not navy as is the rest of my look and feel for all other apps.
Any help appreciated as I'm just starting out...

My code is -

public class GUI extends JFrame {

```
public JMenuBar mainMenu;
public JMenu fileMenu;
public JMenu editMenu;
public JMenu viaPackMenu;
public JMenu viaMenuMenu;
public JMenu viaDesignMenu;
public JMenu helpMenu;

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/*
 *  This is the main class constructor for the GUI
 */
public GUI(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Via Design Package");
    setFocusCycleRoot(false);
    setFocusable(false);
    setFocusableWindowState(false);
    setModalExclusionType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalExclusionType.APPLICATION_EXCLUDE);
    setName("DesignFrame"); // NOI18N
    setEnabled(true);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
            GUIWindowOpened(evt);
        }
    });

    mainMenu = new JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
    viaPackMenu = new JMenu("Via Pack");
    viaMenuMenu = new JMenu("Via Menu");
    viaDesignMenu = new JMenu("Via Design");
    helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

    mainMenu.add(fileMenu);
    mainMenu.add(editMenu);
    mainMenu.add(viaPackMenu);
    mainMenu.add(viaMenuMenu);
    mainMenu.add(viaDesignMenu);
    mainMenu.add(helpMenu);

    setJMenuBar(mainMenu);
}

private void GUIWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setResizable(false);
}                                          

public static void main(String args[]){
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

}

### Thanks in advance

GOT IT! Had to post here though.

Thanks for helping, I've tried lots of commenting out and changing and the answer was how I started. I first did the GUI in Netbeans, found I wanted more freedom so did the same in Eclipse but I copied for the most part the code that Netbeans had generated.

It had generated -

```
mainWindow.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

which needed to be changed to true, I still need to dig further as I can't see why it would want this behaviour!

I'll get the hang of this yet, thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

It works only change is required as per under.

```
private void GUIWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            setResizable(false);
            setSize(screenSize);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Keval I did that but it's still the same, it detaches when I click and drag title bar, strangely it now does this on mouseup not down now. I added a println after the if in main to see what laf is and it says "Metal", I don't know if this is a problem but everything else I use does what I expect, standard windows navy title bar but my app is grey title bar, also the windows menu top left does not display when clicked but if I double click it will close - UPDATE, I placed the println before the if statement in main and it loops twice first is "Metal" and second is "Nimbus"

Comment: @Phil cannot get your problem. please elaborate it. so i can understand.

Comment: the fact that it detaches from maximised (app is max'd, click and drag title bar and it un maximises, since adding the sizing code just means it has a small border unlike maximised which has no border) is something I can live with as most apps do this anyway but for some reason the title bar is not blue like everything else I use and the windows menu (clicking top left on title bar where the java icon is) does nothing unless I double click, then it will exit. I'm thinking maybe a dialog might work, GUI will be working on fixed size graphics so trying to avoid layout/resizing problems

Comment: @Phil so your problem is that when you double click on java icon it will exit from the program. and you want to stop it may i right?

Comment: that bit is ok but a single click on the icon should show the windows menu (restore, move, size, minimise, maximise and close Alt+F4), it does not. Also the colour of the title bar is grey not blue. I have just tried a couple of different look and feel settings and I see a blue bar slowly show at top of app then once it opens fully this goes grey, it's as if it lost focus but the menus(file,edit etc) and top right minimise and X still work

Answer (score 0):

For the titlebar to look like other apps, you will have to use the native look and feel:

```
try {UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());}
catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: I tried it and it was just the same even though it returned windowslookandfeel... My problem was elsewhere, see my answer and thanks